# multiple drawing areas in java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

i have a java applet that i have written that draws a representation of a game tile.

here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestApplet extends JApplet
{
   Tile tile01;
   Drawer drawer;

   public void init()
   {
      tile01 = new Tile("tile01", 4, 2, 1, 7, 0, 6, 5, 3);
      drawer = new Drawer();
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      drawer.drawTile(g, tile01);
   }
}
```

it all works fine to draw one tile, but what i was wanting to do is to have a grid of drawing areas, that a tile can be drawn onto each.

sorry, im not sure if i am explaining it properly, but i want to use swing to divide the space up into a grid of tile-sized panels that a tile can be placed into on a players turn, and when that happens, it re-draws the board with the new tile there.

i am just having a bit of trouble working out how the paint method works, is it possible to use the same paint method for multiple panels? would i have to have a separate graphics object for each panel so that they can have their own local coordinate systems?

anyway, any help would be appreciated, if any clarifications are needed then please let me know.

thanks

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a custom control (the easiest will be to extend either JPanel, JLabel or JButton depending on what you need to do with it) and put the drawing code in that custom control. You can then put multiple copies of that one custom control into your layout.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt think of doing that, that actually makes it a lot simpler. If I was to use a JButton, is it possible to change the drawing on the button once it is pressed? Or is the drawing initialised with the button and unable to be changed once initialised? I would like to use them for tiles on a board which are able to be rotated when clicked.

Comment: `paintComponent` gets called every time the component is redrawn. You can cause a redraw using `repaint()`. This means you can change how the control looks whenever you like.